# Possible to Send a Variable to a PHP Form from a Secondary Submit Button?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, submit

This is quite the pickle...

I have a regular HTML form with a couple option selects and what not, which eventually has a submit button to send the variables to my PHP file (header.php). I also have a second submit button, which submits the form fine, but the issue is I would like to have a text field where the user can type their e-mail ONLY when using the second submit button (which would send the e-mail as a variable to header.php). And since the submit buttons are outside of the  tags, I can no longer add the user's e-mail as a variable to the same header.php.

**Is it possible to add the e-mail field content as a variable to the HTML form from a secondary submit button which sends the HTML form variable AND the submit button variable to header.php?**

Or is there an easier/another way to do something similar to this?

Thank you very much, any help would be terrific.

Comment: Your questions reads a bit wired. Maybe if you add some image it becomes more clear what you're trying to do? And you can check which submit button has been pressed by giving each one a different name.

Comment: if you have jQuery in use, easy to manipulate the forms ..using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes.  Sounds to me like you'll want an interim form-handling page.  Like so:

**form-handle.php**

```
if (isset ($_POST['email_address']) && isset ($_POST['SecondSubmitButton'])) {
  include ('process-second-form.php');
}
if (isset ($_POST['FirstSubmitButton'])) {
  include ('header.php');
}
```

Then in each file process them how you need to.  Does this help at all?  Hope I haven't misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can create to forms to do this the first from just for sending variables to your php file and the other for sending just the email i hope that was helpful and i didn't misunderstood